# Why this behavior for javascript code?

Tags: javascript

Recently one of my friends asked me the output of following code

```js
var length = 10;

function fn() {
    console.log(this.length);
}

var obj = {
  length: 5,
  method: function(fn) {
    fn();
    arguments[0]();
  }
};

obj.method(fn, 1);
```

I thought the answer would be 10 10 but surprisingly for second call i.e. `arguments[0]();` the value comes out to be 2 which is length of the arguments passed.
In other words it seems `arguments[0]();` has been converted into `fn.call(arguments);`.

Why this behavior? Is there a link/resource for such a behavior?

Comment: Well it calls the `0` function of thr `arguments` object. So thats similar to `a.b()` were `b` is called in `a`s context. Still interesting...

Comment: the `arguments[0]` does not hold a reference to the function `fn` declared before it's limited to it's own scope where `this` refers to the `arguments` array.

Comment: Here's a resource to look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context

Comment: @floor yes thats somehow related, but no, this is not a dupe.

Comment: Both calls are returning the number of arguments given to fn(), one is doing it through this, the other is executing the function given as argument[0], if you were to add arguments to the line `obj.method(fn, 1);` it would be reflected in the console output. The this keyword uses function scope so the function scope of this when invoked is the containing function method() so any arguments passed to method would be included in the this.length property.

Comment: Agree with @Jonas that this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The difference is because of the `this` context of each method call.

In the first instance, because the call is merely `fn();`, the `this` context is `Window`. The `var length = 10;` variable declaration at the top happens in the root/Window context, so `window.length` should be `10`, hence the `10` in the console from the first function call.

Because `arguments` is not an array but is actually an Object of type `Arguments`, calling `arguments[0]()` means that the `this` context of the function call will be of the parent Object, so `this.length` is equivalent to `arguments.length`, hence the `2` (since there are 2 arguments). (See [@Travis J's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48835844/2464706) for a more thorough explanation of this part.)

If you were to add

```
this.fn = fn;
this.fn();
```

to the `method()` function, the result would be `5`.

Comment: I would like to add to this answer this screenshot as a proof: https://imgur.com/a/OEOIs  `this` in this case is the argument

Comment: I think just to be clearer maybe you can mention arguments[0] is actually `arguments.0` and hence due to dot notation this refers to arguments object.

Comment: "dot notation" has nothing to do with this, and you cannot use `.0` like that anyway. I fully agree with this answer as written, the ExecutionContext which holds the this binding is that of the Arguments object. It is explained very well in my opinion.

Comment: @TravisJ I know you cannot use `.0`. However, my point is that arguments being an object with a property 0 is being referred to using bracket notation arguments[0].

Comment: @PankajShukla - The values are not properties of the arguments object. Please see my answer for an expansion on this topic.

Comment: @TravisJ I just added a link to your answer for clarity's sake

Answer (score 5):

It is due to how [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context) works within the various scopes in which it is referenced.

*Notice the outputs of the `this.toString()` and you will see what the referenced target is.*

Starting with calling the function `f` directly from the Window, `this` will reference `Window` and thus the length will be `Window.length` which has been declared to be `10`.

Moving on to if we assign `f` directly as a method of `obj`, then `this` would reference `obj` and thus the length will be `obj.length` which has been declared to be `5`.

Where it gets interesting/confusing is when you pass in `f` as a parameter to function `method` of `obj`.

*NOTE: The outcome here will be browser specific. Run it in Safari and Chrome and observe the different outputs.*

On both browsers: `arguments[0]()` is pseudo equivalent to `arguments.0()` (although not syntacticly allowed for `arguments`) which is exactly the same behavior observed earlier with `obj.fn()` which means `arguments` is the reference target. Which as noticed is the number of arguments passed to `obj.method`.

The execution of `fn` inside of `method` is how a callback function works for which you can find a more expansive answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback).

```js
var length = 10;

function f() {
    console.log(this.toString());
    console.log(this.length);
}

var obj = {
  length: 5,
  fn: f,
  method: function(fn) {
    fn();
    arguments[0]();
  }
};

f()
f(1);
obj.fn();
obj.fn(1);
obj.method(f, 1);
obj.method(f, 1, 2);
```

Comment: Upvoted for the reasoning arguments[0]() is pseudo equivalent to arguments.0().

Answer (score 1):

[@musicnothing is fully correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48832900/1026459), the **`this`** binding is different between the two different calls to `fn`.

However, there still seems to be some confusion as to the reasoning for why **`arguments`** is now the **`this`** target which I will address.

**[`this`<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)** bindings are held inside of **[Execution Contexts<sup>ECMA</sup>](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3)**, which are essentially what manages scope in JavaScript.

When a function is called, an **`arguments`** object is constructed. The **`arguments`** object has its own Execution Context, which means it has its own this binding, its own Variable Environment, and its own Lexical Environment. When constructed, the **`arguments`** object values are stored in its Variable Environment, making any references from that point relative to the **`arguments`** object's Execution Context.

By design, the **`arguments`** object is array-like, which basically means it agrees to have a length property, and more vaguely that accessing an index which is less than the length property should have a value. As a result you can access its value references with indexes through a facade, however, it is important to keep in mind where they are scoped to at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is 10 ,2 due to different values of "this".

1. when fn() called , that time this will refer window object . and in window object length is a property which value is 10.
2. when arguments0 called , this refers method . where method is a function and every function have a length property which value is number of parameters passed at the time of call.

Comment: The answer 10 is never given as an output, because the this keyword binds to a function, the only time in this code 10 would be returned is if you included a line outside  a function definition `this.length` in order to access the global length inside a function you would have to use window.length. So your answer is half right.

Comment: When fn() called , this was referring to window object. And here length is a property in window object. So its value is 10. "So your answer is half right" , i did not get this , can you explain ?

Comment: Yes, what was important was the binding of the 'this' statement. But, the code has been changed now so all arguments are moot, now it's time to close the question or remove your answer or it will get down voted when someone happens upon it and it doesn't match up to the code. There is a whole page on MDN on the binding of 'this' and it also varies between using strict mode and not using strict mode.